# Dynamic UI - SelectInput Not Showing

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

Thank you all in advance for your help.

I'm still relatively new to R-Shiny and I'm trying to explore dynamic UI. I've done some research into renderUI, reactive, and observe functions but I'm still not sure of the right way to go about doing what I'm trying to accomplish which is:

1. User selects Y - dynamically populates choices based on loaded data in global.r
2. User selects X - dynamically populates choices based on loaded data in global.r
3. R plots the two

**My problem** is that the select inputs do not display - that makes sense to me given they are reactive. How do I show those select inputs when the page loads?

ui.R

```
require(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
 tabPanel("Pineapple",

     tabPanel("",
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  helpText("Choose X and Y"),
                  uiOutput("pineapple.pick_Y"),
                  uiOutput("pineapple.pick_X"),
                ),
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput("pineapple.plot")
                )
              )

     )
 )
))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session){

output$pineapple.plot <- renderPlot({
  df <- data.frame(blue = c(1,2,3),
                   red = c(4,5,6), 
                   boy = c("steve","steve","bill"), 
                   girl = c("stacey","lauren","stacey")
  plot(input$pineapple.pick_X,input$pineapple.pick_Y,data=df)
})

output$pineapple.pick_X <- renderUI({
  selectInput("pineapple.x", label = h6("Select X"),
                          choices = c("blue","red"),
                          selected = "blue")
})

output$pineapple.pick_Y <- renderUI({
  selectInput("pineapple.y", label = h6("Select Y"),
              choices = c("boy","girl"),
              selected = "boy")
    })
})
```

Comment: Can you also provide sample data please that you use in the app...

Comment: I can't because the data is proprietary, but on that note, I'll edit the post to eliminate that question.

Answer (score 0):

Found a way around it - There wasn't a need to a dynamic UI really, just used variables I stored in global.R to pull the choices.

Thanks!